# Entity Framework: Schema Only

Tags: entity-framework

I am using VS2012 and EF (System.Data.Entity v 4.0.0.0).  I created a database-first model via the designer.  How can I create an instance where it does not actually go to the database?  Is there a swtich that tells the current context to not use the connection string and just make an in-memory representation of the graph?

I then tried making a empty constructor to the conext as recommended [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetentityframework/thread/488949dc-1c6c-444a-a6cc-d35361203808): 
and now I have key violations...

Comment: EF is for saving data in a database. If you want in-memory storage, you are looking for something else. You could use simple collections of the entity objects, if you wanted.

Comment: You can't create an instance of DbSet<Type>.  You mean create my own collection (eg: list<Type>)?  And then switch back and forth depending on my needs?